# Loop through multiple dicionaries and get name of dict in which value is

Tags: python

I want to loop through multiple dictionaries to find a value residing in it. If the value is found, I want values and THE NAME of the dict returned. I have written a function to do it but I cannot extract the name only the complete dict. Here is the code:

```
a = {1: ((1,1),999), 2: ((2,2),998), 3:((3,3),998)}
b = {1: ((4,4),997), 5:((5,5),996)}

def retOBJECT(tup):
    for l in [a,b]:
        for v in l:
            if tup in l[v]:
                return l,v,l[v][1]

print retOBJECT((1,1))

>>> 
({1: ((1, 1), 999), 2: ((2, 2), 998), 3: ((3, 3), 998)}, 1, 999)
```

I do not want the whole dictionary returned but only its name so I know where the other values come from, i.e. the last two numbers.

And this is how I want it to look like:

```
>>> ('a', 1, 999)
```

Can anyone help here. I have always found excellent advice here and I am looking forward to some genius pointing out how to retrieve the name of a dictionary.

Comment: you can't, `a` is just a reference to a dictionary object, it's not a string.

Comment: As Ashwini pointed out, the objects themselves don't have an actual name.
A possible sollution would be to revise your object layout, and include a string somewhere in them. Creating a as a Tuple of string, dict might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def retOBJECT(tup):
    for l_name, l in [('a',a),('b',b)]:
        for v in l:
            if tup in l[v]:
                return l_name, v,l[v][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are just references to the dictionary objects, So whenever you use `a` and `b` python actually uses the objects they are pointing to.

Though you can use `globals()` to achieve what you were trying to do, but I don't know why would you wanna do that:

> globals() -> dictionary
>
> Return the dictionary containing the current scope's global variables.

```
In [110]: globals()['a']
Out[110]: {1: ((1, 1), 999), 2: ((2, 2), 998), 3: ((3, 3), 998)}

In [111]: def retOBJECT(tup):
        for l in ['a','b']:
                for v in globals()[l]:
                        if tup in globals()[l][v]:
                                return l,v,globals()[l][v][1]
   .....:             

In [112]: print retOBJECT((1,1))
('a', 1, 999)

In [113]: print retOBJECT((2,2))
('a', 2, 998)

In [114]: print retOBJECT((5,5))
('b', 5, 996)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the name of the dict, I would suggest giving the dictionary a `'name'` key, which holds the 'name' of the dict.

```
a['name'] = 'a'
```

You could also make `a` a tuple with the 'name' of the object, and the dict.

```
a = ('a', some_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended way would be wrapping your entire data structure in a dict, something like:

```
names = {}
names["a"] = {1: ((1,1),999), 2: ((2,2),998), 3:((3,3),998)}
names["b"] = {1: ((4,4),997), 5:((5,5),996)}

def ret_name(tup):
    for k1, v1 in names.iteritems():
        for k2, v2 in names[k1].iteritems():
            if v2[0]==tup:
                return names[k1], k1, names[k1][k2][1]


print ret_name( (1,1) )
print ret_name( (5,5) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your dicts as keyword arguments to the function:

```
a = {1: ((1,1),999), 2: ((2,2),998), 3:((3,3),998)}
b = {1: ((4,4),997), 5:((5,5),996)}

def ret_obj(tpl,**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
        for k2,v2 in v.iteritems():
            if tpl in v2:
                return (k,k2,v2[1])

ret_obj((1,1),a=a,b=b)
#returns ('a', 1, 999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys. There are a few really valuable results, but I explicitly like ilmiacs, volatility and root's approach, since they are straightforward and easy to implement.  I am glad that you helped me solve this problem and I can tackle my project. Cheers !!